# Spring Cloud - Micoservice Authentication propagation

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am building an application using microservice architecture. I am using `Eureka` for service discovery with `Spring Cloud Gateway` for request routing. For authentication mechanism I am issuing JWT tokens (in auth service). What is the best practice when it comes to propagating Authentication so I can get logged user information in each service which is after the gateway?
So far I've came up/found couple of possible solutions:

1. In gateway add headers for relevant user information, and in each service create filter which would take said headers and create `Authentication` object and store it into `SecurityContextHolder`. The downside of this approach is I can't just plug and play services outside my application.
2. Pass the token coming from the client through the gateway to the each service, where I would have `JWTFilter` which would validate token and extract the user information. Downside I see with this approach is I have to have jwt secret shared between each service or stored on each service, and I would have to implement `JWT` logic, producing duplicate code.
3. Final solution is having something like `oAuth` token introspection endpoint in auth service which would be called from each service (filter) once the request reaches it.

I implemented the filter logic for validating the user token in the gateway service, but I would like to use role based authorization on each endpoint (service) differently (ie. user service has endpoint for creating users (ADMIN), and for fetching user information (ANY ROLE)).

Answer (score 0):

I opted for something like your option 2 and use spring-boot to configure JWT decoder from an OIDC authorization-server (Keycloak).

Configuring OpenID resource-servers is [super easy](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) (more options in parent folder), and authorization-server JWT public signing key is retrieved automatically by spring JWT decoder.

All that is required is ensuring that `Authorization` header with JWT bearer is correctly propagated between services.